# Mount does not work in script when run by php

Tags: debian, mount, sudo, php, exec

So I have a script that's placed in my apache2 html folder and should be executed by an http post. The script requires root (I know that's not safe at all, ignore that please), so I set the user www-data at the sudoers file to `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`. Running the script works quite good except for mounting an cif filesystem.

The script is executed by php:

```
exec("sudo ./miniosetup $folder $address $path $User $Pass $S3User $S3Pass $Port");
```

The script is supposed to mount like this:

```
ipadress=$(host $address | cut -d' ' -f4 | head -n 1)
echo "$ipadress $minuname $minpwd" >> log_mount
echo "mount -v -t cifs //$address/$usePath/ /mnt/$filesystemname/ -o username=$username,password=$password" >> log_mount
sudo mount -v -t cifs //$address/$usePath/ /mnt/$filesystemname/ -o username=$username,password=$password >> log_mount
if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "mount  -v -t cifs //$ipadress/$usePath/ /mnt/$filesystemname/ -o username=$username,password=$passwords" >> log_mount
  sudo mount -v -t cifs //$ipadress/$usePath/ /mnt/$filesystemname/ -o username=$username,password=$password >> log_mount
fi
```

The log_mount file looks like this:

```
192.168.0.5 testingUsr testingTest
mount -v -t cifs //srv01/netstorage/testminio/ /mnt/testingTester/ -o username=FILESYSTEMUSERNAME,password=FILESYSTEMPASSWORD
```

Yet when I run `mount` it is never displayed. Neither is the filesystem mounted to `/mnt/testingTester/`. When I run the script manually with the same parameters everything works fine. 
Any idea is appreciated since I am running out of them.

EDIT:
sudo works, otherwise the script would just output "Please run as root" as the third line is `if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]; then echo "Please run as root" exit; fi`

EDIT:
I have thought that apache2 might run in a kind of sanbox, can anyone either confirm or deny?

Comment: Are you sure `sudo` works when called from PHP? You should check the error output. If your script actually runs, you could do something like `exec >> some_logfile` `exec 2>&1` at the beginning of the script to redirect all output to a file. I also suggest to check the exit code of all commands in your script.

Comment: @Bodo yes sudo works, otherwise the script would just output "Please run as root" as the third line is `if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ];
  then echo "Please run as root"
  exit;
fi
`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all clarification or requested information there instead of answering in comments. Add the lines from my previous comment to your script, followed by `set -x` and show the resulting output in `some_logfile`.